# lookup() Method of javax.annotation.Resource not found when using JDK 10

Tags: java, maven, jakarta-ee, java-10

I do have a JavaEE7 application, that compiles well under Java 8. Now I want to migrate to Java 10 and I have a problem with the maven build inside a single class. Here is the snippet:

```
import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.ejb.Singleton;
import javax.inject.Inject;

import org.infinispan.Cache;

@Singleton
public class TestCacheProducer {

    @Resource(lookup="java:jboss/infinispan/testcache")
    private org.infinispan.Cache<Long, byte[]> testcache;
```

I am using the following versions to compile my sources to java 10:

- maven (3.5.4)
- maven-compiler-plugin 3.8.0
- Java 10 (subversion 2)

with the recommended changes in pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.annotation-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.2</version>
</dependency>
```

and

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.8.0</version>
  <configuration>
      <source>10</source>                                                
      <target>10</target>                                                
      <release>10</release>                                              
      <executable>javac10</executable>                                   
      <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
      <compilerArgs>
         <arg>-proc:none</arg>
         <arg>--add-modules</arg>
         <arg>java.xml.bind</arg>
         <arg>--add-modules</arg>
         <arg>java.xml.ws.annotation</arg>
      </compilerArgs>
  </configuration>
  <dependencies>                                                         
    <dependency>                                                       
        <groupId>org.ow2.asm</groupId>                                 
        <artifactId>asm</artifactId>                                   
        <version>6.2</version>
    </dependency>                                                      
  </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

Inside eclipse (photon) the correct Interface class can be resolved, but when I use maven via a mvn install, then I get these compiler errors.

```
error: cannot find symbol
            @Resource(lookup="java:jboss/infinispan/testcache")
                      ^
      symbol:   method lookup()
      location: @interface javax.annotation.Resource
```

I investigated in this error, but I only found people that used a compiler, or a JavaEE Version reference (below JavaEE 6) where the interface class did not have the "lookup" Method. This is not the case here

my maven version info (mvn -v):

```
Apache Maven 3.5.4 (1edded0938998edf8bf061f1ceb3cfdeccf443fe; 2018-06-17T20:33:14+02:00)
Maven home: C:\Softdev\maven\apache-maven-3.5.4\bin\..
Java version: 10, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-10
Default locale: de_AT, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 7", version: "6.1", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"
```

I also used `mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose` to see, if there is any dependency, what references an older implementation. Is there any possibility to see, from which referenced file this compile error comes from?

Thanking you in advance for any hint or help.

Comment: are you using the dependency on the `modulepath` (does your project module have `module-info.java`)?

Comment: No, I do not have such a file. Is it optional or a must-have requirement?

Comment: Depends on if you're modularising your application or just trying to execute the same using a different JDK. And if the file is not there, the code shared by you should work just fine.

Comment: Thanks for the information, i just wanted to start by getting it simply compiling and running under Java 10 with only necessary changes to achieve this

Comment: I was unable to reproduce the error using the above maven minimal configuration, could you share the complete [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which fails for you. Maybe some transitive dependencies are actually the cause here.

Comment: Specifying javax.annotation as a dependency and at the same time compiling with `--add-modules java.xml.ws.annotation` is very strange but doesn't explain the compilation error. Is it possible to get mvn to print the javac command that it is executing - should be easy to diagnose this if you can find out the javac command that is actually executed.

Comment: is there any possibility via maven to List the available jar files along the classpath that contains a specific class? (e.g. like in eclipse IDE when pressing CTRL+SHIFT+T for opening types)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for all your help. 
The Problem was caused by the **maven-processor-plugin** I had to also add compiler arguments for the JDK 10. (the module named 'java.se.ee' includes all JEE modules and you do not need to include them one by one)

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.bsc.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-processor-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.3</version>
     <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>process</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>process</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <configuration>
                <fork>true</fork>
                <addCompileSourceRoots>true</addCompileSourceRoots>
                <compilerArguments>--add-modules=java.se.ee -J--add-modules=java.se.ee</compilerArguments>
                <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/metamodel</outputDirectory>
                <processors><processor>org.hibernate.jpamodelgen.JPAMetaModelEntityProcessor</processor>
                </processors>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <dependencies>  
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```